Swift try error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not
if let tenorReceived = try JSONDecoder().decode([TenorModel].self, from: responseString){
    

}

I'm getting the error Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[TenorModel]'
how to fix this?
I HAVE TO use try and not try? so I can catch errors, how to do this?

use do { } catch { } statement insteald of if let { }

Why not try to calm down and look at the code you have instead of posting another question in anger. When do you need to use if let and is this really such situation?

Remove the if

after removing it: Requirement from conditional conformance of '[TenorModel]' to 'DecodableWithConfiguration' (Foundation.Array) and 'decode(_:from:configuration:)' declared here (Foundation.JSONDecoder)

The error says that the decode() returns a non-optional value: an array of TenorModel objects - [TenorModel].
Since if let is a conditional binding that needs to be used with an optional type and your output is non-optional (meaning you will get an array no matter what, even if it's empty), the error makes sense.
This should do it:
do {
    let tenorReceived = try JSONDecoder().decode([TenorModel].self, from: responseString)
    // Now you can safely use tenorReceived
    if tenorReceived.count > 0 {
        print("Array not empty")
    }
} catch {
    // Handle the error (e.g., print(error))
    print("Failed to decode: \(error)")
}


if let expects an optional type to unwrap, but try either succeeds (and returns a non-optional value) or fails by throwing an error. This makes do-catch the appropriate construct for handling errors in this case.
